# cron curl not working

Tags: curl, cron

I have a question I am trying to have curl upload a file using ftp to a server.  The syntax below works when I run in manually it works but when I have cron run it I see no attempts on my logs in my ftp server with an attempt.  Can someone let me know what I am missing? thx

```
## Backup ##
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -T $HOSTNAME"_""`date +"%m%d%y"`.txt" ftp://192.168.1.100/FTP-ROOT/ --user cookie:cookie >> /var/tmp/ftp_log
```

Comment: Is the first column in your `crontab` entry really `*/5`?

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/tmp/ftp_log`? What directory is `$HOSTNAME"_""`date +"%m%d%y"`.txt"` in? Is `$HOSTNAME` set for cron correctly?

Comment: Yeah made it 5 misn to test yeah I forgot to add directory /var/tmp I just added and its still not working and their is nothing in ftp_log file                         /usr/bin/curl -T /var/tmp/$HOSTNAME"_""`date +"%m%d%y"`.txt" ftp://192.168.1.100/FTP-ROOT/ --user cookie:cookie >> /var/tmp/ftp_log

Comment: ignore last comment its working now I just missing path /var/tmp.  Thx for help